# Java program for beginner dealing with storing data in arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have to read an unknown amount of integers from standard input until zero is read, store them in an array, preform calculations on those numbers, then output results based on the calculations. 
I am stuck on the first step, reading the numbers from the input, and storing them in an array. And then being able to use the data in the array to preform the needed calculations.

thanks!

Comment: Reading an unknown number of values is going to be difficult if you can't use some kind of `List`, you could cheat and store them in a `String` and then split when your done, but you'd need to convert each value back to an `int`

Answer (score 3):

You should use

`ArrayList<Integer>`

instead of `Integer[]`.
That will help you a lot, you will not have to deal with unknown count of integers, because the list will resize automaticaly. If you need any additional info, you are welcome to ask.

Then you can convert your list to an array like this:

`Integer[] array = list.toArray(new Integer[list.size()]);`

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't know the number of integers so better to use List. Use `scanner.nextInt()` to read integer from input

Answer (score 0):

For reading from a standard input you can use Scanner. Create a new scanner and use System.in as the constructor Input Stream.

Now decide how many integers you will need and make an array that matches that size. If you don't know how many integers you'll get you have to use something like an `ArrayList` and later put those values into an array.

To store the integers, then, you'll need a loop that sets each member of the array to your input, which can be read with something like `scan.nextInt()`

then you'll use a for loop to iterate through your completed array and do whatever math you wish to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    .......
    ArrayList<Integer> dataList=new ArrayList<>();  // array of size unknown
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);  
    int yourInputData=0;
    do{
        yourInputData=input.nextInt();    // read input from user
        dataList.add(yourInputData);     // store in the array list
    }while(yourInputData!=0);        // loop until zero (0) is entered

    input.close();                // close resources
   .............              // do your calculation
```

Answer (score 0):

public class MAIN {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> sentence = new  ArrayList<String>();

    for (String string : args) {
        if(!string.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
            sentence.add(string);
        } else{
            break;
        }
    }
    String[] stockArr = new String[sentence.size()];
    stockArr = sentence.toArray(stockArr);
    System.out.println(stockArr.length);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
    Integer i;
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // create an array list
                                                    // to store indefinite
                                                    // data
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        i = sc.nextInt();
        if (i == 0) {
            break;
        }
        list.add(i); // all data storing in list
    }
    Integer[] array = list.toArray(new Integer[list.size()]); // convert
                                                                // list to
                                                                // array of
                                                                // size of
                                                                // list
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        System.out.println(array[j]);
        // now u can do whatever calculations u want to do
    }
```